# Critical guava memory leak - Workaround needed

Tags: java, web-applications, memory-leaks, guava

Is there any way to workaround the [Google Guava r15 **memory leak** (link to the bug report)](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=1553) in the cache component?

(Without relying that the application server might clean things up and/or considering that the web application will never be restarted/redeployed)

Answer (score 11):

<strike>I guess you don't need to care about it.</strike> The Tomcat message says

> Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.

IIUIC it means that once all old threads are gone, so will all the pointers to the old version of your class.

*Details:* The reason for the thread pooling is the big cost of thread creation. The pooling itself is hacky as you get a thread which was doing something else and thread are not stateless. Thread creation is expensive assuming you'd need a lot of them and never recycle them. There's nothing wrong with renewing all threads every few minutes, so I hoped, Tomcat's workaround solves it perfectly. *But it's not the case.*

#### EDIT

I'm afraid, I misunderstood something. The linked bug says

> It seems that web applications which are using guava cache might face a memory leak.
> After several redeployments, the application container crashes or stalls with an OutOfMemoryError.

I thought Tomcat could solve it easily, but for whatever reason it doesn't. So I'm afraid, you have to clean the `ThreadLocal`s yourself. This is easily possible via reflection, the concerned fields are `Thread.threadLocals` and possibly `inheritableThreadLocals`. It's a bad hack and the harder part is to make this happen when nothing can go wrong, i.e., when no application is loaded.

#### EDIT 2 and 3

I guess it's safe to do something like

```
Stripped64.threadHashCode = new ThreadHashCode();
```

as the contained things are only needed for performance under heavy contention and they get recreated upon use. *But according to MRalwasser's comment, it won't help at all as alive threads will still refer the old value. So there seem to be no way.*

As `ThreadLocal` works by storing data with the threads (rather then using a real `Map<Thread, Something>`), you'd have to through all threads and remove references there. Fooling around with other threads' private fields is a terrible idea as they are not thread-safe and also due to visibility issues.

Another thing that might or mighn't not work is my proposal on the [issue page](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=1553). It's just a 20 line patch. Or simply wait, the issue has been assigned yesterday.

#### EDIT 4

Thread locals which don't get used can't cause any problems. AFAIK the only use of this TL is in cache stats. So avoid both `CacheBuilder.recordStats` and `Cache.stats` and `Stripped64` won't get loaded.

#### EDIT 5

It looks like it's gonna get fixed finally. From the [issue](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=1553):

> Doug fixed this upstream for us and we patched it back into Guava:
> http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/cgi-bin/viewcvs.cgi/jsr166/src/jsr166e/Striped64.java?revision=1.9

At the first glance [his change](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/cgi-bin/viewcvs.cgi/jsr166/src/jsr166e/Striped64.java?r1=1.8&r2=1.9) seems to be identical to [mine](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/issues/attachment?aid=15530005000&name=Guava-issue1553-Fix_memory_leak_due_to_Stripped64.HashCode.patch&token=HCctJ0oz58q8J0RItdQ1LJRcowo%3A1399404838476).

#### EDIT 6

Finally, this has been marked as fixed and [Guava 18.0-rc1](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/guava-discuss/gEpjTrm6tNY/eyvSnQQkMRYJ) has been announced. It's just sad it took that long given that the change is the same as mine (9 month ago).

Comment: Your guess in EDIT 2 seems to be not correct. All alive threads are still referencing the thread local values if any has been set, even if you eliminate the reference to the ThreadLocal itself

Comment: I award the bounty to you because of the hint to a possible workaround disabling cache stats. However, it's a workaround which hurts - vetter ideas (or guava's final fix) are still very welcome.

Comment: Can't you [patch](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4971686/java/Guava-issue1553-Fix_memory_leak_due_to_Stripped64.HashCode.patch) it yourself? The solution is pretty simple, I'd hope it'd work, but use at own risk.

Comment: @maaartinus Thanks for your effort, but having hope might not be enough for going into production, especially when multi-threading safety and scalability come into play. Would you mind proposing your patch to the official issue so that the community can take a look? Thanks!

Comment: @Don Miller: Done. I haven't tested it so there may be some trivial bug there, but I wouldn't expect any problems concerning multi-threading safety and scalability as it does exactly the same as the original, just with JVM classes instead of own ones.

Comment: @MRalwasser: Could you kindly vote to reopen [my provocatively titled question asking about the deeper cause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19692413/why-do-some-webservers-complain-about-memory-leaks-they-create). And thank you for the bounty.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ServletListener ClassLoaderLeakPreventor https://github.com/mjiderhamn/classloader-leak-prevention/ which also clears ThreadLocals on undeploy/stop. It also has fixes/workarounds for other common leaks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a drawback of ThreadLocals. You'll get the same every time you put an application level class in ThreadLocal.

The only workaround is to restart server on deploy I guess. I think it's a known issue of Java applications. Are you sure that it's the only place that stops unloading classloader?